# 'packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal Release' while installing Wine

Tags: apt, 20.04, wine

I was trying to install Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 but I am receiving this error:

```
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Whole command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                 
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                              
Ign:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal InRelease                                                         
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                     
Get:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease [7,343 B]                                              
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease                                                           
Err:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal Release                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 40.65.182.21 443]
Hit:11 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                       
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/docky/ubuntu focal InRelease            
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.3 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20220223)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
deb https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal main
# deb-src https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod. focal main
deb https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
# deb-src https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
```

Microsoft-prod.list

```
deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
```

Comment: Why are you using a microsoft repository? Why do you have 21.04 and 20.04 repositories referenced on the same computer? Your sources list appears to be a train wreck.

Comment: Unless you have a specific need for an advanced version of wine, I suggest reverting all that you have done, and installing the version from the Ubuntu (not microsoft) repos.

Comment: I am trying to install stable version of wine on 20.04. I pasted the 20.04 command line from WineHQ site in terminal. I don't know why it's showing microsoft repo

Comment: It appears that your basic issue stems from a messed up sources list. I suggest you edit your question and include the full text of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the text of any files ending in `.list` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: I have files 4 files ending with .list: Microsoft-edge.list , microsoft-prod.list , opera-stable.list and ricotz-ubuntu-docky-focal.list

Comment: I suggest deleting the ppa's from Microsoft and the wine hirsute ppa.

Comment: I suggest deleting *all* the ppas out of the sources.list and deleting the microsoft-prod.list as well, unless you have a known, specific reason for retaining each one. You could use `synaptic` to determine what is installed on your system from each of the ppas.

Comment: I don't know how to delete it because I'm very new to linux.

Comment: I deleted packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod from Sources.list and now I am able to download wine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't actually coming from the installation of Linux Wine but rather from a persisting issue that is causing an error during installation. In this case, it seems to be coming from the Microsoft repository not being installed correctly. The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod' seems to be configured for the "lunar" release, but Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa") does not have a release named "lunar". Pretty much, you installed the wrong version of the Microsoft repository and so you need to either remove the current one or update it to the correct release.

You could try something along the lines of:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod lunar'
```

to remove the incorrect repository. And then, reinstall it if you wish.